# Is it acceptable practice to unit-test a program in a different language?

Tags: python, c++, unit-testing

I have a static library I created from C++, and would like to test this using a Driver code.

I noticed one of my professors like to do his tests using python, but he simply executes the program (not a library in this case, but an executable) using random test arguments.

I would like to take this approach, but I realized that this is a library and doesn't have a main function; that would mean I should either create a Driver.cpp class, or wrap the library into python using SWIG or boost python.

I’m planning to do the latter because it seems more fun, but logically, I feel that there is going to be more bugs when trying to wrap a library to a different language just to test it, rather than test it in its native language.

Is testing programs in a different language an accepted practice in the real world, or is this bad practice?

Comment: I'm not sure if what your professor does qualifies as **unit** test.

Comment: ...or even **test**. Did you really say "random test arguments"?

Comment: @Prinzhorn Throwing random inputs at a program is a valid (and sometimes quite effective) [testing strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_testing). But yes, it's not unit testing.

Comment: @delnan you're right, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_test which is quite effective on mobile (random taps etc. until the app crashes)

Comment: As a sidenote: the main reason it's not a unit test is because random input is not reproducible (which is a requirement for a unit test)

Comment: as a comment inspired by Greg Young's Later, I think in theory it's a good idea to use a dynamic language for TDD in the tests, if not in the production code, because then you don't have to distinguish between failing to compile and failing.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Random tests can be made reproducible if you keep the seed used to generate the inputs.

Comment: I think it's fine and have done exactly the same thing with C++ libraries exposed through boost python.

Comment: This is called integration testing, not unit testing. It's perfectly valid and is used by lots of big name software houses (Nokia uses Perl, some NASA projects use embedded tcl to make tests scriptable etc.). But you should still do unit tests. Unit tests and integration tests are different beasts and large complex software systems use both.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd say that it's best to test the API that your users will be exposed to. Other tests are good to have as well, but that's the most important aspect.

If your users are going to write C/C++ code linking to your library, then it would be good to have tests making use of your library the same way.

If you are going to ship a Python wrapper (why not?) then you should have Python tests.

Of course, there is a convenience aspect to this, as well. It may be easier to write tests in Python, and you might have time constraints that make it more appealing, etc.

I guess what I'm saying is: There's nothing inherently wrong with tests being in a different language from the code under test (that's totally normal for testing a REST API, for instance), but make sure you have tests for the public-facing API at a minimum.

---

*Aside, on terminology:*

I don't think the types of tests you are describing are "unit tests" in the usual sense of the term. Probably "functional test" would be more accurate.

A unit test typically tests a very small component - such as a function call - that might be one piece of larger functionality. Unit tests like these are often "white box" tests, so you can see the inner workings of your code.

Testing something from a user's point-of-view (such as your professor's commandline tests) are "black box" tests, and in these examples are at a more functional level rather than "unit" level.

I'm sure plenty of people may disagree with that, though - it's not a rigidly-defined set of terms.

Comment: So an actual unit test is very likely to be tested using the same language in order to get access to the function without testing a whole load of extra API code.

Comment: @JamesRyan correct. Unit tests usually live along side the code with the goal of testing every tiny little piece of code in the smallest realistic pieces. This is fantastic for quickly locating bugs. Functionality testing can cover a functional piece of code that runs through thousands of lines and has tons of methods and all you know at the end is did it work or not? With proper unit testing you can identify the offending method in seconds narrowing your search to typically a twenty lines of code or less.

Answer (score 10):

A few things to keep in mind:

1. If you are writing tests as you code, then, by all means, use whatever language works best to give you rapid feedback. This enables fast test-code cycles (and is fun as well). **BUT**.
2. Always have well-written tests in the language of the ***consumer***. How is your client/consumer going to call your functions? What language will they be using? Using the same language minimizes integration issues later on in the life-cycle.

Answer (score 5):

Why not, it's an awesome idea because you really understand that you are testing the unit like a black box.

Of course there may be technical issues involved, what if you need to mock some parts of the unit under test, that may be difficult in a different language.

This is a common practice for integration tests though, I've seen lots of programs driven from external tools such as a website from selenium, or an application from cucumber. Both those can be considered the same as a custom python script.

If you consider the difference between integration testing and unit testing is the number of things under test at any given time, the only reason why you shouldn't do this is tool support.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on what it is you are trying to test. It almost always makes sense to write unit tests in the same language as the code you are testing so that you can construct the objects under test or invoke the functions under test, both of which can be most easily done in the same language, and verify that they work correctly. There are, however, cases in which it makes sense to use a different language, namely:

1. Integration tests that run a number of different components or applications together.
2. Tests that verify compilation or interpretation failures which could not be tested in the language, itself, since you are validating that an error occurs at the language level.

An example of #1 might be a program that starts up multiple different servers connected to each other, issues requests to the server, and verifies those responses. Or, as a simpler example, a program that simply forks an application under test as a subprocess and verifies that it produces the expected outputs for a given input.

An example of #2 might be a program that verifies that a certain piece of C++ code will produce a static assertion failure or that a particular template instantiation which is intentionally disallowed will result in a compilation failure if someone attempts to use it.

To answer your larger question, it is not bad practice per-se to write tests in a different language. Whatever makes the tests more convenient to write, easier to understand, more robust to changes in implementation, more sensitive to regressions, and better on any one of the properties that define good testing would be a good justification to write the tests one way vs another. If that means writing the tests in another language, then go for it. That being said, small unit tests typically need to be able to invoke the  item under test directly which, in most cases, means writing the unit tests in the same language  as the component under test.

Answer (score 4):

I would say it depends on what you're actually trying to test. For true **unit testing**, it is, I think, best to test in the same language, or at least a binary-compatible language (i.e. testing `Java` with `Groovy` -- I use `Spock` in this case, which is `Groovy` based, to unit-test my `Java` code, since I can intermingle the `Java` with the `Groovy`), but if you are testing **results**, then I think it's fair to switch languages.

For example, I have tested the expected results when given a specific set of a data when running a `Perl` application via `nose` in `Python`. This works because I'm not unit testing the Perl code, per se, but the outcomes of that Perl code.

In that case, to unit test actual `Perl` functions that are part of the application, I would use a `Perl`-based test framework such as `Test::More`.